# Interpretation of results logit model with interaction term

Tags: regression, logistic, interaction, regression-coefficients

I have run a pooled logit regression (using R) with a dependent variable of probability of CEO turnover. I have several binary and continuous independent variables, and an interaction term between binary and continuous variable.

I am confused about interpreting the results, since interaction term does not have a marginal effect, and it is said that interpreting the logit model coefficients do not make much sense.

What do you recommend to interpret the results, especially the interaction term?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! How would you interpret the interaction coefficients in a linear model?